# Greasemonkey get names of all open tabs

Tags: javascript, tabs, greasemonkey

My ultimate goal is to have an autocompleting list that displays all open tabs (in Firefox), which I can reduce to the tab I want to switch to next.

I can do the completion / combobox etc, but I don't know how to get the list of all names (and favicons wold be a huge bonus). Would be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't GreaseMonkey run in the context of a single web page? I don't think it can access the other tabs.

If you make a normal extension, you can call `window.getBrowser().browsers` as is described here:

[Detecting tab closed (after closed) from firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572466/detecting-tab-closed-after-closed-from-firefox-extension)

Aside from learning a little XUL, your extension might be easy to port.

[How to build a FireFox Extension](http://lifehacker.com/264490/how-to-build-a-firefox-extension)

If you just want the functionality, here's an add-on that does what you want already

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/list-all-tabs-menu/

Comment: There is a roundabout way to do this in GM using `@include *` and `GM_setValue()`.  Not recommended though, so I didn't post an answer.  Using the existing extension is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something like this for Greasemonkey. This adds the titles of all newly opened tabs to the `ttl` string. You have to place `//@grant GM_getValue` and `//@grant GM_setValue` at the beginning of the userscript.

```js
var ttl = '';
ttl = GM_getValue('ttl');
ttl += document.title+',';
GM_setValue('ttl', ttl);
console.log('opened tabs:\n'+ttl);
window.addEventListener ('beforeunload', deleteTtl, false);
function deleteTtl (zEvent) {
    ttl = GM_getValue('ttl');
    ttl = ttl.replace(document.title+',','');
    GM_setValue('ttl', ttl);
}
```